# Div, grad, rot in projective geometry?

Tags: reference-request, projective-geometry, differential-operators

Is it possible to define generalisations of the grad, rot and div operators
in classical projective geometry using homogenous coordinates?

I know for example in $RP^2$ that the grad of a homogeneous function $c: F(x,y,z)=0 \leftrightarrow F(\rho x,\rho y, \rho z)=0$ gives the coordinates of the tangent line in point $(x,y,z)$ to the curve $c$.

A literature reference or a link to an article is also appreciated.

Comment: No, these operators actually are metric-dependent. The application you are aware of to find the tangent line (or hyperplane, in more dimensions) is valid because of Euler's Theorem for homogeneous functions. The homogeneous function, it should be noted, is *not* a function on projective space. So what do you want to try to do in general?

Comment: I take the euclidean equation of an electric field line or equipotential line. I make it into an homogeneous function $f$ and use $(f_x, f_y, f_z)$ as a parameter equation of the curve's tangents. Bc. this is a grad, I thought maybe when I dualize it for the case of a bundle of planes through one point, I might get an interpretation of rot.

Comment: I was somehow suspecting that rot might be - apart from a certain interpretation - the dual of grad in some way.